# Seeing signs of life in our Meyer Lemon tree

Tags: diagnosis

We’re in Austin, Tx and thought we for sure lost our lemon tree in the freeze. This morning we see small green stems coming from the base. My question is should we cut back the tree to the highest growth or be more patient and let it do it’s thing? There are tiny sprigs as high as 4 ft up the tree, btw